# JBOSS_HOME is not properly being set in Linux, System.getenv from Eclipse returns null

Tags: java, linux, jboss, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

I've added JBOSS_HOME both in Linux and Windows.

Here is my arquillian.xml

http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

```
    <container qualifier="NON_REST_CONTAINER">
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
        </protocol>
        <configuration>
            <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        </configuration>

    </container>

     <container qualifier="REST_CONTAINER"  default="true">
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
        </protocol>
        <configuration>
            <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container> 
</group>
```

In windows tests are running fine but in Linux I'm getting following exception: NullPointerException due to jbossHome variable being null in ManagedDeployableContainer

```
        final String jbossHome = config.getJbossHome();
        File jbossHomeDir = new File(jbossHome).getCanonicalFile();
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Arquillian has previously been attempted initialized, but failed. See cause for previous exception
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:112)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:94)
    ... 81 more
```

Particularly caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:94)
... 81 more
```

So, what I'm interpreting is JBOSS_HOME is not being read properly by Arquillian not sure why.

When I added jbossHome property in arquillian.xml it's working fine in Linux also. But I don't want to do that since path will be different for Linux and Windows and I want it to be compatible.

Any suggestions/pointers would be much appreciated.

Update:

I tried **System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME")** from a standalone program and ran it from terminal and it prints JBOSS_HOME, but from my eclipse/testcase it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eclipse you can set the `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable from the JUnit test launcher, in the `Environment` tab. This is a workaround in case the environment variable was not defined at the system level (not the shell level).

In Eclipse,

- Open the launcher configurations dialog using the "Run configuration..." menu in the main toolbar (using the arrow on the right side of the Run icon).
- Then select the JUnit test that you want to run, select the Environment tab and click on New to add the JBOSS_HOME env variable to the test you'll run.

Comment: Thanks, However, I defined in /etc/environment and it is working.

Comment: Could you define steps so it would more helpful?

Comment: in Eclipse, open the launcher configurations dialog using the "Run configuration..." menu in the main toolbar (using the arrow on the right side of the Run icon). Then select the JUnit test that you want to run, select the `Environment` tab and click on `New` to add the `JBOSS_HOME` env variable to the test you'll run.

Answer (score 2):

Define key value pairs in **/etc/environment** file. Now logout and login to make the changes applied. It will make these variables available for all processes.

```
JBOSS_HOME=<JOBSS-PATH>
```

So, you don't have to run the eclipse from the Terminal shell to make environment variables visible.

It worked for me.